# Object mapping and translation with Restkit 0.20

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a JSON object that I would like to map into two core data objects with a relationship between the two.

For example, if the JSON is:

```
{
 "name"    : "tom",
 "company" : "ACME",
 "phone"   : "123-456-7890",
 "email"   : "aaaaa@bbbbb.com",
 "height"  : "60",
 "weight"  : "172"
}
```

I would like to parse the JSON object into a Person object that contains the "name" field. The person object would then have a relationship to a contactInfo object that contains the "email" and "phone" field, and another relationship to a bodyStats object that contains the "height" and weight "field". What is the best way to do this? I fairly proficient with normal RestKit mapping but this one has stumped me, can I achieve this with dynamic mapping? Do I have to use key validation and custom map objects?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you need to parse the JSON objects and then create CoreData entities?

Answer (score 0):

Set up 3 different response descriptors, linked to your 3 model classes. Each response descriptor should specify the same path pattern and keypath (if the JSON isn't nested as per your question then use a `nil` key path).

The key is to use foreign key mapping, based on the `name`. This means adding transient attributes to the `contact` and `stats` entities and configuring their mappings to connect the relationship to the `person` entity with the specified `name`.